# How to query Start and End Elements in Order from an Array?

Tags: mongodb, nested, mongodb-query

I have a query but I don't know how to write
I have tour collection with embedded points.

```
{
    _id: "my tour",
    points: [
        {_id: '1', point: 'A'},
        {_id: '2', point: 'B'},
        {_id: '3', point: 'C'},
        {_id: '4', point: 'D'}
    ]
}
```

When user search tour start at B & end at C  I want to list this document

But when user search: start at C & end at B the tour will not be listed.

How I can write the this query?

Comment: db.getCollection('tour').aggregate( [
   { 
       $match: {
            'points': { 
                $elemMatch: {$and:[
                    {
                        country: 'US', 
                        point: '598c156bfd081c2ca0d82319'
                    } ,
                    {
                        country: 'US', 
                        point: '598c156bfd081c2ca0d82335'
                    } ,
                ]}
            }
       }
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here since there are "two" conditions on the array entry selection:

```
var start = "B",
    end = "C";

db.getCollection('nest').find({ 
  "points": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "point": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }   
    } 
  }   
})
```

Would select the document since the conditions are true for both the elements with "B" and "C", but reversing the order:

```
var start = "C",
    end = "B";

db.getCollection('nest').find({ 
  "points": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "point": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }   
    } 
  }   
})
```

The condition is not true for any array element since no element has a value both greater or equal to "C" and also satisfies less or equal to "B".

So that's how you enforce the order, and it's fine as long as the data itself is always ordered that way.

If you have data that is itself presented in reverse:

```
{
    _id: "my tour",
    points: [
        {_id: '4', point: 'D'},
        {_id: '3', point: 'C'},
        {_id: '2', point: 'B'},
        {_id: '1', point: 'A'}
    ]
}
```

And you do want to "start" at "C" and end at "B" indicating forward progression by "array index", then you need a calculated statement:

```
var start = "B",
    end = "C";

db.getCollection('nest').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
     "points.point": { "$all": [start,end] } 
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {  
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$gt": [
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$points.point", start ] },
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$points.point", end ] },
          ]}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

So the best advise here is to keep the array ordered that is searchable for a lexical range, since you can do with calculation but the raw query is far more performant.

Comment: You can't use $gte and $lte in this case.

Comment: @thankdev You can if you design it right. I was actually still writing, after a meal break that is. Read and understand.

Comment: How do you think if we add more field to combine these conditions
["A-B", "A-C", "A-D", "B-C", "B-D", "C-D", "A-A", "B-B", "C-C", "D-D"]

Comment: It works. Thank you.
$and: [
          { "$lte": [
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$points.point", start ] },
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$points.point", end ] },
          ]}
        ]

Comment: @thankdev Good. Now please realize that the question you actually asked was in fact answered by the initial query state, and a comparison of index positions is not actually required when the data analyzed is lexically ordered. When you ask a question here you do not normally get to apply,*"Well what about if I change it to this then?"*. Such a thing is actually where you [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and in the future that is what you need to do.

Comment: Your advice very useful. Thank you.